Exchange properties from Camel are being "copied" to the Message header
Consider the following route:
from("direct:init")
    .setProperty("any", constant("some value"))
    .choice()
        .when().simple("${header.any} == null", Boolean.class)
            //POINT A: should get here, as we expect 'header.any' as null
        .otherwise()
            //POINT B: but it gets here. But how? We do NOT expect any value for 'header.any'

It's supposed to reach "POINT A". However, it reaches "POINT B". I was wondering what could be stored inside "header.any" so I decided to set its value to the Message body:
(...)
.otherwise()
    //POINT B: but it gets here. But how? We do NOT expect any value for 'header.any'
.end()
.setBody(header("any"));

As long as I used 'header("any")' I was expecting a null body. However, surprisingly, the content of the property "any" was copied to the body. I set a breakpoint after 'setBody()' and I've found this:"
Click here to see headers values
Please note headers size is equal to 0 (zero). So how could the exchange property "any" be copied to body even if I use "header()" component and headers is empty? Is there something I'm missing here?
I'm using Camel 4.5.0, Spring Boot 3.2.4 and Java 20
Thanks everyone
